# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

As most of the people gets an error while using google map like 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `SOMETHING` of undefined ',

likewise i too get the error, but my error SOMETHING is `text`, 
Full Error Message as follows :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
callback
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
d
(anonymous function)
```

I even used Google's Snippet https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix

and just modified Locations, i.e.

```
var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.728156999999996, -74.077642);
var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(18.470410048659726, 73.83044242858887);
```

i think it shouldn't matter, coz when i change these locations to

```
var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(19.14322218193555, 73.135986328125);
var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(18.470410048659726, 73.83044242858887);
```

then it works perfectly fine,

calculateDistances method is as follows :

```
function calculateDistances() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin1],
      destinations: [destinationA],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: There is no connection over land.

Comment: @AntoJurković , do you mean to say it cant calculate duration between 2 countries ?

Comment: It can't calculate distance if there is ocean between points.  `response.rows[i].elements;` is an array with object which has status property `status: "ZERO_RESULTS"`. In that case there is no `distance` property and for loop fails. There should be already similar question...

Comment: @AntoJurković geocodezip , thanks for sharing your thoughts, response.rows[0].elements[0].status is giving ZERO_RESULTS